# Add TOGGLE to "show div when text is entered"

Tags: jquery, input, toggle, jquery-events

The user is able to see options appear beneath a input field when they start typing.  This is the Javascript that currently does this:

```
    #number {
    display:none;
    }
    
    <body onload="
    $('#gname').bind('keyup change',function(){
    if(this.value.length > 0){
    $('#number').show();
    }
    else {
    $('#number').hide();}
    });
    ">

    <input type="text" id="gname">

    <div id="number">
        testing testing
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to also give a user the option to toggle on the div before they type as well, and also to toggle off the div once it's appeared after typing...

Any ideas on how to manipulate the code?

Comment: what are the users actually going to use to toggle it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `toggle()` function - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LUqzK/1/)

```
$(function() {

    $('#gname').on('keyup change', function() {
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            $('#number').show();
        } else {
            $('#number').hide();
        }
    });    

    $("#hint").on("click", function() {
        $('#number').toggle();
    });

});
```

**UPDATE**

To disable the hint to re-appear after it was disable by the button click - simply unbind the event listeners from it:

```
$("#hint").on("click", function() {
    $('#number').toggle();
    $('#gname').off('keyup change');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LUqzK/2/)

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I had this as a possibility earlier and the issue with it is that when you start typing again the div reveals again. think there's anyway to keep kind of deactivate the typing reveal once the toggle is hit for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the focus and blur functions for it.. Try this

```
$('#gname').bind('keyup change blur', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
        $('#number').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#number').hide();
    }
});

$('#gname').on('focus', function() {
    $('#number').show();

});​
```

[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GEqv8/1/)

Comment: thank you for your quick response.  I had this as a possibility earlier and the issue with it is that when you start typing again the div reveals again.  think there's anyway to keep kind of deactivate the typing reveal once the toggle is hit for the first time?